# Is there any property to get vertical plane detection?

Tags: ios, scenekit, ios11, arkit

I am creating an AR app for iOS 11 and I want to find the surface of vertical objects like a wall or any object with height. I can see there is a property for  planeDetection horizontally which calls a delegate method:

```
- (void)renderer:(id <SCNSceneRenderer>)renderer didAddNode:(SCNNode *)node forAnchor:(ARAnchor *)anchor
```

So is any way to detect surface vertically?